# Display full Addressbook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, addressbook

How do I display the full addressbook in a table using the UITableview and Addressbook classes?

Comment: Add some more details or your question will be closed. count down begins.. oops, there are already 2 close votes

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go right ahead and guess Cocoa/Obj-C and the system Address Book.

I'm also going to assume that you know the basics of setting up an `NSTableViewDatasource` object.

[This page at developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AccessingData.html) should be instructive; on a related note, you probably want to use the people picker provided by the AddressBook.framework.

Comment: Lot of assumptions - Even though I don't know anything about cocoa or obj-c, you'll get my upvote if these assumptions turn out to be correct :)

Comment: but i dont want to pick any particular property....
can u please tell me how to give addressbook as sourcecode....

Comment: Williham's right, If you want to show all the address book items, you're better off going with the PeoplePicker view (at least on the Mac, I'm not sure if it's in UIKit).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of below link,i developed the application similar to your query.once go through it.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Hope,this might be helpful for you.

Ramya.