# how to insert addressbook contacts in tableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, addressbook

How do I insert addressbook contacts into a tableview?
i got stuck with this. Please help me find out guys.

Comment: This is just a reworded equivalent of your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686483/display-full-addressbook You should add more details of what you've tried / where you've got stuck to get answers that might actually help you.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is rather vague, I pressume you want to make an application which interacts with the contacts on the iPhone? If that is the case, there is an Address Book UI framework available to help you develop applications which interact with the native iPhone address book.

Have a look at the Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone OS:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html

The Programming Guide also includes guides on how to access the contacts in the address book directly. There are also several UI controlles available to help you pick a contact for instance.

Once you've got access to the contacts, have a look at the Table View Programming Guide for iPhone OS on how to display data in a table.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot...but i know to pick particular properties of selected people and display it.....Wat i want is when i open my application i need to get the contact book....

Comment: Please elaborate on that, upon launch of your application you need to access the contacts in the address book?